# Rails namespace routes with 'as' parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, routes

I would like to use the `:as` parameter on a namespaced route, like so:

**routes.rb**

```
map.namespace :banana, :as => 'apple', do |banana|
  ...
end
```

But it seems that the `:as` parameter is only available to `map.resources`. Am I missing something, should I refactor my routes?

I'm stuck on Rails 2.3.8 for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:as is for map.resource only, since it is used as a way to override the route, instead of using the Model's class name. Here are the [2.3 Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html)

Why bother with `:as => 'apple'` and just use apple as the namespace?

```
map.namespace :apple do |apple|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Because of the refactoring. All the links with banana_path should now be renamed. But as I come to think of it, it might be not that much of an issue. I hoped there was a backdoor, but apperently there is none.